# can you help me with this simple 'ulimit'?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, ulimit

I have a badly coded infinite looping program that I want to run on the command line - but not forever. I want to use ulimit so if it loops forever, it gets cut off.

I'm trying:

```
$> bash -c "ulimit -t 1; java myinfloopprogram"
```

but it's like nothing is happening. What's going on, is my commandline command wrong? myinfloopprogram runs just fine.

I'm running a terminal and the version is Ubuntu 9.10 .

Comment: Unbuntu? Is that the anti-Ubuntu? :)

Comment: It's not, like, sitting there for a second and then dying is it? Cause I think I might know what the problem is in that case ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the looping program actually using CPU?

-t is for CPU time, not wall clock time, so if your program is not actually using any CPU time it won't be killed.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what it was, about two minutes of running = 1 second of CPU time for this program. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this instead:

```
java myinfloopprogram &
pid=$!
for i in $(seq 1 60); do
    kill -0 $pid >/dev/null || break
    sleep 1
done
kill -0 $pid >/dev/null || kill -TERM $pid
```

Answer (score 1):

`ulimit` is probably not what you need. You need some sort of bash timeout feature. There's nothing built into bash, but there are a few scripts floating around to do this. eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687948/timeout-a-command-in-bash-without-unnecessary-delay